# Esri Feature Layer not loading in Leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, esri

I am having trouble getting an ESRI Feature Layer loading in a Leaflet map I have made in R.  This works fine using JavaScript, but it won't work in R.  Is there a compulsory argument that I am missing?

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.esri)

n <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
  setView(lng = -0.83925784, lat = 51.411721, zoom = 12) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery, group = "ESRI World Imagery") %>%
  addEsriFeatureLayer(url = 'https://services.arcgis.com/JJzESW51TqeY9uat/arcgis/rest/services/SSSI_Units_England/FeatureServer/0',
                  useServiceSymbology = TRUE) %>% 
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap", "ESRI World Imagery"))
n
```

Comment: that code worked for me just now https://duaw26jehqd4r.cloudfront.net/items/33381H3i393c14411U44/Screen%20Shot%202018-12-12%20at%209.58.46%20AM.png

Comment: Thanks @sckott.  Interestingly, it works in a browser, but not in  the RStudio viewer.  My mistake, apologies.

Comment: i don't use rstudio, so i guess that's why it worked